# bash script to create symlinks from a file contain a list of paths

Tags: bash, command, symlink

I have a file that contains a set of paths

```
~/somedir/pathfile.foo
--------------------------
/home/user/dir/file1.bar
/home/user/dir/file2.bar
/home/user/dir/file3.bar
/home/user/dir/file4.bar
...
```

I would to write a bash script (or command) that would create symbolic links to all these `.bar` files within the current directory (.).  For clarification, if `pathfile.foo` contains N paths I would like to have N symlinks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while read line; do ln -s "$line" "${line##*/}" ; done <pathfile.foo
```

After the above has been executed, the following symlinks will appear in the current directory:

```
$ ls -l *bar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 me me 24 Oct  8 23:09 file1.bar -> /home/user/dir/file1.bar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 me me 24 Oct  8 23:09 file2.bar -> /home/user/dir/file2.bar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 me me 24 Oct  8 23:09 file3.bar -> /home/user/dir/file3.bar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 me me 24 Oct  8 23:09 file4.bar -> /home/user/dir/file4.bar
```

Comment: Oldie but a goldie.